# Userscript to provide quick access to canonical questions when voting to close duplicates

Tags: script, app-request, voting

ServerFault often gets off-topic questions which are closed as duplicates of a canonical question, such as [capacity planning](https://serverfault.com/q/384686/115189) or [I've been hacked](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/115189). I've favourited those canonical questions for quick access, but whenever I encounter such an off-topic question I have to open my profile, go to the favourites tab, copy the question URL, and then paste that into the VTC dialog.

What would be great is if these canonical questions could be made accessible when the VTC dialog is opened and Exact Duplicate is chosen. Actually listing them in the VTC dialog, similar to the other lists of potential duplicates, would be even better. The list of questions could either be manually configured, or taken from my favourites.

Is there a script which does something like this, and if not, does someone feel like writing one? ;-)

Comment: Are you still looking for this? I'd be happy to try and make one :)

Comment: I'm not very active on ServerFault any more,  so I don't really need this now. Thanks for the offer :-)